# get distinct record from 3 tables using join in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

i have three tables
cases,clients,attendance

in cases

**id    start_date    end_date      client_id   status**

1     2012-12-30    2013-01-30     1          new starts

2     2012-12-31    2013-01-31     2          probation

in clients

**id    Name          dob            gender     status**

1     TOM      1987-01-30          M          A

2     JERRY    1985-01-31          F          D

in attendance

**id    client_id     date               status**

1     1             2013-01-30         A

2     1             2013-01-31         P

i need result like this

**case_id      case_start_date      case_end_date     client_id        Name 
      att_date                   atte_status**

1            2012-12-30           2013-01-30         1                TOM
      2013-01-30,2013-01-31      A,P

is this possible? i'm a self learner and i don't have good idea in join query please any body help me....

Comment: There must be 1001 *answered* questions on SO already about how to join tables. Please search for one or read a book on table joins/SQL/databases. A good place to start might be the "Related" column to the right.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$this->db->select('ca.*,ci.Name,a.date,a.status');
$this->db->from('cases'.' ca');
$this->db->join('clients'.' ci','ca.client_id=ci.id','left');
$this->db->join('attendance'.' a','a.client_id=ci.id','left');
return $this->db->get();
```

go through the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) if u want to read more about join and active records...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example to get you started with any number of join common fun for all
Construcor Code
Construct `$joins` as array:

```
$joins = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'table2',
        'condition' => 'table2.id = table1.id',
        'jointype' => 'LEFT'
    ),
);
```

Example function handling joins as an array:

```
public function get_joins($table, $columns, $joins)
{
    $this->db->select($columns)->from($table);
    if (is_array($joins) && count($joins) > 0)
    {
        foreach($joins as $k => $v)
        {
            $this->db->join($v['table'], $v['condition'], $v['jointype']);
        }
    }
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```